# Keep form values after submit PHP with cookies

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I am looking for a way to keep form values after submit with cookies (after going to page2 and going back to page_form). I am really trying but i need you help guys.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
<? php
if (isset($_POST['Infos_test']))
{
$expire = 8*3600; 
setcookie("Infos_test", $_POST['from']&|&$_POST['area_html'], time()+$expire);  
}
?>
```

.....

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['Infos_test']))
{
$Infos_test = explode("&|&", $_COOKIE['Infos_test']); 
}
?>
```

.....

```
<input type="text" name="from" style="width:350px"  value="<?php echo $Info_test[0]; ?>"/>

<textarea valign="top" name="area_html" style="width:350px; height:150px; resize:none;" /><?php echo $Info_test[1]; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: If you want to store that in cookies then follow up http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp or else you need to store in session or post method go with below answers

Comment: Is your PHP code at the very top of your output? Cookies must be set before any other HTML output. Even a space character can break that.

Comment: even a BOM can break it (if you have created the file with notepad.exe for examle and saved it as utf8).

Comment: Thanks for answering, @jtheman it is in the very top but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Rafee I already tried with cookies but doesn't work i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Your HTML form syntax is very wrong! First there is no such thing as an `<input type="textbox"` - also you shouldn't assign a value to a textarea with the attribute `value` but add it as the content. Also you end the tag with the closing `/>` instead of actually taking use of `</textarea>`... Do you even have a form input named `"Infos_test"`? Maybe nothing is set because you dont post your data correctly. Please post your entire code (all relevant parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using SESSION variables before cookies. Here is an example code:

On the form recieving page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['from'] = $_POST['from'];
$_SESSION['area_html'] = $_POST['area_html'];
```

Then on your other page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- here is your html header etc -->
From: <?php echo $_SESSION['from']; ?><br>
Area HTML: <?php echo $_SESSION['area_html']; ?>
```

Note that the `session_start();` part must be stated BEFORE any other HTML output.

HTML syntax for form should read:

```
<input type="text" name="from" style="width:350px" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['from']; ?>" />
<textarea valign="top" name="area_html"><?php echo $_SESSION['area_html']; ?></textarea>
```

Note the type of the INPUT tag and the change how values should be inserted into a TEXTAREA.

Comment: It worked, with some little modification
    $_SESSION['area_html'] = $_POST['area_html'];
   
in the same page
    <textarea valign="top" name="area_html" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['area_html']; ?>" /></textarea>

Thank you @jtheman and thanks everybody, i'm a newbie here and i'm very satisfied by the quality of answers/answerers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but i should say that it works only on chrome (but not in firefox or opera) i tried to activate cookies but it still doesn't work in other navigators

Comment: The problem is with my form because it leads to another script
<form name="sendForm" method="post" action="test.cgi">
and when i click on back everything disappear; I thought i worked fine with chrome but chrome remembers every input without introducing code. Any idea ?

Comment: I suppose `test.cgi` is not a PHP document, but Perl script or similar? Then there is no way you can use PHP to set either cookies nor session variables - which mean the question can't be answered other than that you cannot add PHP code to a non-PHP script!

Comment: There is a way to transfer variable session from php to perl and vice versa my form is a php file but submit leads to a perl script. May be i should post another question about this.

Comment: Sure, but you are using PHP tags `<?php ...` in your syntax which one guesses belong to the recieving script - which is Perl? Yes, since this setup is quite non standard, you should post another question and be sure to add code from all involved scripts and tag the question with both PHP and Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can save form values in the php session using `$_SESSION` variable and not the cookies.

here are several tutorials which help you to do this.

[session_php 1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) [session_php 2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code in `test.php` and run & refresh it.. you will understant how it worked.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    echo "Values from POST <br />";
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";


    $post_arr = $_POST;

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post_arr);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r(serialize($post_arr));
    echo "</pre>";

    $expire = 8*3600; 
    setcookie("Cookie_Info", serialize($post_arr), time()+$expire); 




}


if (isset($_COOKIE['Cookie_Info'])) {
    $data = unserialize($_COOKIE['Cookie_Info']);
} else {
    $data = array(
        'from' => '',
        'area_html' => ''
    );
    /* in above array add what ever fields in a form with same field name */

}

echo "This is what we get from cookie";
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

?>

To view Cookie, it need browser refres one time <br />


<form name="test_form" method="post">

<input type="text" name="from" value="<?php echo $data['from']; ?>" /> <br />
<textarea rows="3" name="area_html" ><?php echo $data['area_html']; ?></textarea> <br />
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />


</form>
```

Comment: I tried that one but when i go to my form i don't find the input box next to 'from' neither the data above (they disappeared). The error i got is  "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array " for the lines <?php echo $data['from'];?> and <?php  echo $data['area_html']; ?>"

Comment: There's an typo in the answer, should be `<?php echo $data['from']; ?>` (not `$date`). Also `<? php` should be `<?php>` ...

Comment: Thank you very much Rafee i'd like to put a +1 to every answer but i don't have enough reputation, anyway thank you all :)

Comment: It works as test.php but when i try to include your code in mine the first input disappears with the rest of the form Bizarre !. error is : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: can you show your code, where you are including. and let me know what kind of error it displays

Comment: I replaced this 
    <input type="text" name="from" value="<?php echo $data['from']; ?>" /> 
with this
    <input type="text" name="from" style="width:350px" value="<?php echo $data->from; ?>"/>
I got no errors now but In firefox, nothing happens, even the cookie is not created (i verified this with FireBug).

Comment: The problem is with my form because it leads to another script
<form name="sendForm" method="post" action="test.cgi">
and when i click on back everything disappear; I thought i worked fine with chrome but chrome remembers every input without introducing code. Any idea ?

Comment: Here, its working good with all browsers, i dont know why does it accept with `OO` style. And i never worked on `cgi` scripts.

Comment: The redirection to the perl script is the problem, when i tried you code with <form action="test.cgi" ... it doesn't work, seems like i have to find a way to transfer session variable from php to perl and vice versa.