# On go back form Resubmission error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, confirm

http://ichangeitall.com.au/
 On  the link above, when you will click on get .. you will see a form in which there are check boxes.. and when you move forwards you will see the same type of form. as we go on to the third page and click on back, the browser says CONFIRM RE-SUBMISSION.
How should i get rid of it so that the values that we have checked should be auto selected?

Comment: Have you tried any solution? Make some efforts before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONFIRM RE-SUBMISSION is google chrome related error. I recommend to follow the best programming/coding practices and use session / cookies during form submissions. Look at this tread [Keep form values after submit PHP with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033612/keep-form-values-after-submit-php-with-cookies). I guess it will be helpful.

Alternatively you can Google for how to store values in cookies on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

One way to partly do it  is to pass answers from Stage I to Stage II AND III than pass them after "back" button to stage II using POST method. That should remember Stage I answers.